# How to use temporary table slug in database?

Tags: codeigniter

This query not working

SELECT word_name, word_id  from words where REPLACE(slug, '-', ' ') like '%word%' AND  1=1  ORDER BY
 length(word_name) ASC LIMIT 8

P.S EDIT : sorry I gave up on this quetion. Please ignore this question.

Comment: # in mysql means the rest of the line is a comment, and there is no such thing as #tables in mysql. Might help if you explained what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail: 1. what you mean by "in single row" and 2. why you need temporary tables

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you need all those steps. You can check for existance, define and select all in one statement for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create temporary table if not exists t 
(id int)
select id from users;
```